# Magento 2: How Insert on Duplicate works in this case?

Tags: magento, magento2

I am using Magento 2.1.7. In my database table, I need to **create a row** / **Update a row** based on ItemNo and GroupNo group.

[image: Refer to this image to see the example table structure]

For example, I need to update the Qty based on ItemNo and GroupNo combination.If the combination doesn't exist, then a new row to be created.

How is this possible using Insertonduplicate in SQL query?

Comment: Please clarify your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

After creating your model and resource model, you can insert on duplicate using the load method (Although deprecated).

```
        $itemNo = 1000;
        $model = $this->modelFactory->create();
        $model->load($itemNo, "ItemNo (Field in DB)");
        $model->addData([
            "Item No" => $itemNo,
            "Group NO" => 20,
             "Qty" =>  300

        ]);
        $saveData = $model->save();
        if($saveData){
            echo "data saved sucessfully";
        }
```

This creates new row if itemNo does not exist in DB and update the row if it is there